# ASP.NET Core IIS Application Pool Compatibility

Tags: iis, asp.net-core

I have my ASP.NET Core application running on IIS and the Application Pool is currently set to .NET CLR Version 4.0. My application loads up correctly and the my view is displayed. However, when I try to run a `POST` I get the following error:

`502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.`

I realize that most documentation says to set the .NET CLR Version to `No Managed Code` for .NET Core, but is it possible to run ASP.NET Core against v4.0? I am targeting .NET Framework 4.5.2 in my .NET Core app.

Comment: [IIS acts as a mere reverse proxy for Kestrel and won't execute any managed code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/aspnet-core-module). Even if you compile your ASP.NET Core app against .NET Framework 4.6, IIS will simply pass through the requests.

Comment: @CodeCaster - So what I'm trying to do is simply not possible...thanks for clarifying.